# GPUpdate fails with 1129 and 1006 errors in System event log

Tags: group-policy

Freshly installed windows 10 client (hyper-v VM), joined the domain, cannot update group policy from DC. Rejoining the domain did not solve the problem. W10 has static IP, DNS is configured, A record is added to DNS (manually). DNS is on the same machine as DC. There are 2 DCs in the domain. 
If it helps, there is 8018 error also (system failed to register host resource records for network adapter). Client is resolving other hosts in the domain correctly (nslookup).
I checked a lot of articles about it, but still cannot find the solution for this.
Thank you!

Comment: can you successfully ping both DCs from the client? Do you have NTP setup and are all clocks in sync?

Comment: Yes, ping is working right and the time is synced.

Comment: can you verify that `repadmin /showrepl` and `dcdiag` from a domain controller reports everything is in good status?

Comment: both commands returned successful results in elevated prompt.